# VideoView with a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I am relative new to Android development. I am working on an app where it is a specific client requirement that I have a scrollable list of videos. These videos must be playable within the scrolling list as embedded views.

My first thought was to use VideoViews in a ListView and use a custom ArrayAdapter to instantiate the VideoViews. After running this I get all kinds of errors, such as:

- E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (100, 0)
- E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.IllegalStateException
             at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync(Native Method)
- I/MediaPlayer﹕ path is null
- D/MediaPlayer﹕ Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

Upon further research I found many posts suggesting the VideoViews and ListViews do not play well together because of the way ListView recycles views. Most of these posts are quite old though (circa 2011-2013). My question is, has this issue been fixed or is it a fact that VideoViews should not be embedded within a ListView? If not, is there some other acceptable way of having a scrolling list of embedded video players?

I would have thought this was a fairly common requirement of Android apps. I'm only supporting Android 4.0+.
Cheers