# How Do I Play Video in ListView like Instagram and Vine?

Tags: android, listview, instagram, android-videoview, vine

I'm new to android development and I am trying to play multiple videos in a listview.  Currently, each listview row item is a VideoView.  This approach has not worked as the VideoViews act abnormally when I begin to scroll.  I've researched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982935/instagram-style-multimedia-listview), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235712/videoview-with-a-listview), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896921/android-scrollview-having-videoview-is-giving-problem)  and discovered that VideoViews and TextureViews don't work well within  ListViews and ScrollViews.  How are apps like vine and instagram able to play videos in listviews?  Any help is greatly appreciated?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896921/android-scrollview-having-videoview-is-giving-problem/

Comment: please check the following link 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896921/android-scrollview-having-videoview-is-giving-problem/6832598#6832598][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896921/android-scrollview-having-videoview-is-giving-problem/6832598#6832598

Comment: If you haven't yet found an answer, here is a good article: https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429#.ty01zm2it

Comment: Use this android library to auto play videos https://github.com/eneim/toro

Answer (score 5):

Although the answer is late but i think it might help someone searching for the same. There is a sample app from the github that has implementation for this requirement.:-

https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager

For understanding of code refer to the following link it is really helpful for you:-

https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429

The problem is that there are some limitations in **VideoView** in **listview**
and handling playbacks so this library  implement is the **VideoView** based on the **TextureView**. Here is it how it looks like[image]

Answer (score 0):

For playing videos in Listview, you need to open Video on Item Click of ListView then you can retrieve your video url in String like:

```
String  myUrl = urHashMaparraylist.get(position).get("videolocation");
```

Now pass this myUrl to next Activity and just set this String as a

```
 Uri video = Uri.parse(myUrl);
 videoView.setVideoURI(video);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
     {
        String  myUrl = urHashMaparraylist.get(position).get("videolocation");
        Intent n = new Intent(YourActivityName.this , NewActivityName.class);
        n.putExtra("videolocation",myUrl);
        startActivity(n);    
    }

});
```

Now in your next Activity retrieve it as a

```
Uri video = Uri.parse(url);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
```

In some case,
for setting VideoView,you can use:

```
 android:background:"#0000"
```

as from [Android Scrollview having videoview is giving problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896921/android-scrollview-having-videoview-is-giving-problem/6832598#6832598)

***Instead of VideoView you can also try using TextureView*** for reference you can see number 2 reference:

For more reference for video streaming ... you can check the following url:
1>http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Android-Media-Streaming-Tutorial

2>http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html

Comment: If user want to play video in same place of row item then what he should use?