# video on infinite scroll list

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, android-videoview

I am developing in android (kotlin).

I can't achive the performance or smoothness of apps like 9gag/instagram for making an infinity scroll list of items containing videos.
I am using a ListView for the infinite scrolling, and VideoView to play videos.
any help, article, or best practices for this?

thanks

Comment: See this, It might helpful to you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043642/how-do-i-play-video-in-listview-like-instagram-and-vine?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView instead of ListView with ViewHolder for your video view.

Take Reference from here:
[Create dynamic lists with RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview)

Comment: Refactored my ListViewAdapter and now using RecyclerView with it's propper adapter but performance still terrible.

Comment: Don't do any CPU intesive task in your on createView and in onBind view. Check if any.

Comment: And share your code if possible.